# PCP research proposal

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, pcp, project-topic

Hi I am taking an undergraduate taking a course in Probabilistic checkable Proofs. I will greatly appreciate if you can suggest some good research ideas and pertaining reading for someone who is just getting started. Thanks!

Comment: PCP is a very large area. Could you be more specific about which aspects of PCPs do you want to read about? Also, what did you already learn in your course?

Comment: Topics covered include:

interactive proofs
IP=PSPACE
public to private coins
bounded communication/randomness
doubly-efficient interactive proofs (aka interactive proofs for muggles)
zero knowledge
basic probabilistic checking
exponential-size PCPs (Hadamard)
polynomial-size PCPs (Reed--Muller)
optimized probabilistic checking
redicing query complexity (proof composition, parallel repetition, 3-query PCPs, ...)
reducing proof length (routing, proximity testing to Reed--Solomon, ...) Reducing query complexity. I was thinking about reduction query complexity.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Can you understand the down vote in this question? ... PS: I did not downvote it.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow That was the second question that the user with user name Turbo asked where people got all touchy-feely about. Why aren't people getting touchy-feely about this question? What is wrong with this question that it got a down vote, but nobody wants to discuss why it got a down vote? Double standard as usual

Comment: I did not downvote, but "suggest some good research ideas and pertaining reading" for PCPs is in my opinion both subjective and too broad. But I personally don't feel too strongly about it

Comment: [policy on project topic questions](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/802/)

Answer (score 5):

Here are some recent papers on PCPs with small query complexity that I found interesting:

- [arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1979](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1979)
- [eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2013/179/download](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2013/179/download)
- [wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dinuri/mypapers/DH.pdf](http://wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dinuri/mypapers/DH.pdf)
- [eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2015/085](http://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2015/085)
- [cs.utexas.edu/~danama/papers/par-rep/final3.pdf](http://cs.utexas.edu/~danama/papers/par-rep/final3.pdf)
- [cs.utexas.edu/~danama/papers/par-rep-limit/paper.pdf](http://cs.utexas.edu/~danama/papers/par-rep-limit/paper.pdf)
- [eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2016/160](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2016/160)

Also, [this paper](https://www.math.ias.edu/csdm/files/08-09/rimpagliazzo_new_direct_product_testers_and_2_query.pdf) is somewhat older, but it is interesting and can help understanding the context to some of the previous papers. In addition, if I may recommend a paper of my own, I think [this paper](http://cs.haifa.ac.il/%7Eormeir/papers/derand_parallel_repetition_full.pdf) contains open problems that might be useful.